# Why do "consulting engineers" advise, not consult?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I am interested to find if the two terms *consulting* and *advising* are interchangeable, particularly in business.

Generally, one [consults](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consult) someone else, who [advises](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/advise). That is, the seeker of information is consulting, and the giver of information advises.

However, there are firms of *consulting engineers* and other similar outfits. They don’t consult, they advise, so it appears that the terms are indeed synonymous, at least in certain circumstances. What are those circumstances? The dictionary definitions I found (linked above) don’t mention that *consult* can mean *advise* or *counsel*.

Comment: You consult, I advise.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Yes but "Consulting engineers" do the advising.

Comment: @Andrew: But *consulting engineers* don't so much "consult" themselves, as wait for clients to consult *them*.

Comment: Yes, they aren't doing the consulting, despite the title. There is some ambiguity in how the word is used. The question here isn't particularly well-put, but there is a question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach which none answered

Comment: Well, we can try again.

Comment: Don't down vote good questions, just because you don't know the answer :D -- @AndrewLeach has contributed something helpful.

Answer (score 2):

OED says that this use of the word *consulting* does in fact mean *giving advice* and stems from a now-obsolete sense of the French *consulter, to give (professional) counsel*. They suggest that the word should be parsed as a noun used attributively, rather like "loudspeaker" in "loudspeaker cabinet", "a cabinet for a loudspeaker". Thus a "consulting engineer" is an engineer to whom one goes for ***a consulting***.

> **consulting,** *adj.*
>   2: Applied to a physician, engineer, etc., who makes a business of giving professional advice, either to the public or to those practically engaged in the profession.  [ < French *médecin consultant,* ‘celui qui donne des consultations’ (Littré); from obsolete sense of *consulter*   to give (professional) counsel: compare “consultation” n. 2c. But as now used *consulting* would be understood as an attributive use of the verbal noun.]
>
> **consulting,** *n.*
>   The action of the verb *consult*; consultation. Also attributive, as in *consulting room*.

However, this is the only way in which the word *consulting* is synonymous with anything to do with *advice*. The normal uses are as quoted in the question: one consults someone who advises, and the words are practically antonyms.

Comment: Sherlock Holmes called himself 'the first consulting detective', by analogy with *consulting doctors*. I have always understood that when a specialist is called in, he and the person first called in *consult together*.